# C#: automatic conversion from enum to class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enums

Consider this scenario.

1. There is a `struct` `Color` (written by someone else)
2. There is `enum ColorCode` which implements html named color codes.
3. There's a static function that converts `ColorCode` to `Color`
4. I want to be able to do this:

   ```
   Color tmp = ....;
   tmp = ColorCode.Aqua;
   ```

How do I do this without copy-pasting text 140 times?

I don't really care what `ColorCode` is (enum, class, whatever) as long as the above line works.

**Problem:**

C# does not allow me to define operators for enums.
I also do not have any macros to make some nice human-readable table within `ColorCode`.

**Restriction**:

Contents of `ColorCode` should be available as `int`s, but should be assignable/ convertible to `Color`.

---

Code fragments:

```
public enum ColorCode{
    AliceBlue = 0xF0F8FF,
    AntiqueWhite = 0xFAEBD7,
    Aqua = 0x00FFFF,
    Aquamarine = 0x7FFFD4,
    Azure = 0xF0FFFF,  ///Repeat 140 times
    ...
}

public static Color colorFromCode(ColorCode code){
 ....
}
```

---

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could write an extension method on the enum:

```
public static Color ToColor(this ColorCode colorCode)
{
    ...
}
```

Then you could have:

```
Color tmp = ColorCode.Aqua.ToColor();
```

It's not quite an implicit conversion, but it's as readable as you're likely to get.

Answer (score 2):

You can make `ColorCode` a struct (better than a class, because it really is just a value), and then define an implicit cast from `ColorCode` to `Color`:

```
struct ColorCode
{
    int hex;
    public static readonly ColorCode
        AliceBlue = 0xF0F8FF,
        AntiqueWhite = 0xFAEBD7;
    // and the rest of the ColorCodes

    public static implicit operator Color(ColorCode cc)
    {
        return /* cc converted to a Color */;
    }
    public static implicit operator ColorCode(int cc)
    {
        return new ColorCode() { hex = cc };
    }
}
```

The implicit cast from `int` to `Color` is just to make the definitions for your named color codes easier (so that you can do, for example, `AliceBlue = 0xF0F8FF`). At this point, you can easily and implicitly convert `ColorCode`s to `Color`s:

```
Color tmp = ColorCode.Aqua;
```

Comment: Thanks for the replying. Your suggestion is also good, but sadly I cannot accept two answers at once and I went with john skeet's suggestion for the moment. Nevertheless, thanks for the idea.